# NEFilterProvider record network activity

Tags: macos, network-programming, macos-catalina, macos-system-extension

[NEFilterProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nefilterprovider), or more specifically its 2 subclasses [NEFilterDataProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nefilterdataprovider) and [NEFilterPacketProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nefilterpacketprovider), has the functionality to allow or deny network activity. However, I couldn't find any way to log in the activity, for debugging purposes.

I know the documentation says this:

> it runs in a very restrictive sandbox. The sandbox prevents the Filter
>   Data Provider extension from moving network content outside of its
>   address space by blocking all network access, IPC, and disk write
>   operations.

but is there any trick to log this anyway in debug mode? Maybe using `os_log` or something like that?

Comment: Have you found any tutorials for the NetworkExtension framework? I've been trying to implement a URL blacklister but the documentation is just awful.

Comment: Yeah it’s awful. I haven’t found a good tutorial. There is just one example Apple gives in a video of their conferences.

Comment: @DevShark: Which video is that? could I kindly ask you to provide a link or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use `os_log` and read the output in the Console app.  if you want to workaround the privacy restrictions (while developing/testing), use the `%{public}` prefix, like so...

```swift
import os.log

// ...somewhere in the provider class
os_log("something i want to log %{public}@", someVar)
```

you're right, the documentation is really, really lacking for this area, other than the SimpleFirewall sample code, and wwdc video.  i have an app in production using `NEFilterDataProvider` but it about cost me my sanity to figure out how to put it all together. at some point i'm going to try to write some blog posts or make a demo repo to try to help create a central community resource to share knowledge and fill in the gaps in the documentation with hard-won knowledge.